# R- merging two data sets within time duration/intervals

Tags: r, dplyr

I am still learning R and having trouble trying to merge two data sets from two different data.table and match it within the time interval. For example given table1_schedule and table2_schedule:

> table1_schedule

```
Channel    Program      program_Date    start_time
HBO        Mov A        1/1/2018        21:00
HBO        Mov B        1/1/2018        23:00
HBO        Mov C        1/1/2018        23:59
NatGeo     Doc A        1/1/2018        11:00
NatGeo     Doc B        1/1/2018        11:30
NatGeo     Doc C        1/1/2018        12:00
NatGeo     Doc D        1/1/2018        14:00
```

> table2_watch

```
Person    Channel        program_Date       start_time    end_time
Name A    NatGeo             1/1/2018        11:00        12:00
Name B    NatGeo             1/1/2018        12:30        14:00         
Name B    HBO                1/1/2018        21:30        22:00
Name B    HBO                1/1/2018        22:30        23:30
```

The goal is to merge the programs that run between the "start_time" and "end_time" of the table2_watch table and add the programs watched by the person during that time interval each time. For example,

> The wanted output

```
  Person    Channel   program_Date  start_time  end_time  Prog1  Prog2  Prog3
Name A    NatGeo      1/1/2018      11:00       12:00     Doc A  Doc B  Doc C       
Name B    NatGeo      1/1/2018      12:30       14:00     Doc C  Doc D  -NA- 
Name B    HBO         1/1/2018      21:30       22:00     Mov A  -NA-   -NA- 
Name B    HBO         1/1/2018      22:30       23:30     Mov A  Mov B  -NA-
```

Is there a way to do this in the simplest and most efficient way such as using `dplyr` or any other R commands best for this type of problem? And add the watched programs during the time interval only if it goes beyond 10 minutes then add that the person watched the next program. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution where we can make use `foverlap`.

I'm showing every step with a short comment, to hopefully help with understanding.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert date & time to POSIXct
# Note that foverlap requires a start and end date, so we create an end date
# from the next start date per channel using shift for df1
setDT(df1)[, `:=`(
    time1 = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, start_time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
    time2 = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, shift(start_time, 1, type = "lead", fill = start_time[.N])), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")), by = Channel]
setDT(df2)[, `:=`(
    start = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, start_time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
    end = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, end_time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))]

# Remove unnecessary columns in preparation for final output
df1[, `:=`(program_Date = NULL, start_time = NULL)]
df2[, `:=`(program_Date = NULL, start_time = NULL, end_time = NULL)]

# Join on channel and overlapping intervals
# Once joined, remove time1 and time2
setkey(df1, Channel, time1, time2)
dt <- foverlaps(df2, df1, by.x = c("Channel", "start", "end"), nomatch = 0L)
dt[, `:=`(time1 = NULL, time2 = NULL)]

# Spread long to wide
dt[, idx := paste0("Prog",1:.N), by = c("Channel", "Person", "start")]
dcast(dt, Channel + Person + start + end ~ idx, value.var = "Program")[order(Person, start)]
#   Channel Person               start                 end Prog1 Prog2 Prog3
#1:  NatGeo Name A 2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 12:00:00 Doc A Doc B Doc C
#2:  NatGeo Name B 2018-01-01 12:30:00 2018-01-01 14:00:00 Doc C Doc D    NA
#3:     HBO Name B 2018-01-01 21:30:00 2018-01-01 22:00:00 Mov A    NA    NA
#4:     HBO Name B 2018-01-01 22:30:00 2018-01-01 23:30:00 Mov A Mov B    NA
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "Channel    Program      program_Date    start_time
HBO        'Mov A'        1/1/2018        21:00
HBO        'Mov B'        1/1/2018        23:00
HBO        'Mov C'        1/1/2018        23:59
NatGeo     'Doc A'        1/1/2018        11:00
NatGeo     'Doc B'        1/1/2018        11:30
NatGeo     'Doc C'        1/1/2018        12:00
NatGeo     'Doc D'        1/1/2018        14:00", header = T)


df2 <- read.table(text =
    "Person    Channel        program_Date       start_time    end_time
'Name A'    NatGeo             1/1/2018        11:00        12:00
'Name B'    NatGeo             1/1/2018        12:30        14:00
'Name B'    HBO                1/1/2018        21:30        22:00
'Name B'    HBO                1/1/2018        22:30        23:30", header = T)
```

Comment: `Mov A` runs on HBO from 21:00 until 23:00.  `Name B` watched HBO from 21:30 until 22:00 and then again from 22:30 until 23:30.  He/she therefore saw parts of `Mov A` during both of those periods.  That is how I understood it.

Comment: @d125q Right I get your point. That makes sense. So I guess you're saying entries in the first `data.frame` are sequential (by Channel)?

Comment: @d125q Yup, you're right! It all makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I've made an edit.

Comment: Great; there are both `data.table` and `tidyverse` answers now!

Comment: I was trying to work this out but I have an error in the `foverlaps` line which makes an error in R studio `"Error in foverlaps(dt1_watching, dt2_schedule, by.x = c("Channel", "start",  : 
  All entries in column time1 should be <= corresponding entries in column time2 in data.table 'y' "` How to solve this problem?

Comment: @governator5410 Can you please include (minimal) sample data that reproduces the error you're getting. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: I posted the most simple dput of the watching and schedule sample data in "R- joining tables using time intervals error using foverlaps" I have tried to fix it but the same error keeps on coming up,im still in the learning process on r so im not really sure what the error actually means . thanks

Comment: @governator5410 Did you update your data? If so I cannot reproduce your issue. My solution works for the data you give above.

Comment: its basically the same format but different data. I think i finally found the problem but still not sure. maybe when the end date is created, especially in the time going from 11pm to 1am, the POSIXct format carries the yesterdays date to the 1 am date instead of the actual date because it uses the same row for the date. for example jan/2/2018 11 pm & jan/3/2018 1am. When setting df1 it will say jan/2/2018 1am because it does not consider that it actually has gone to the next day. is this probably why there is error and is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: @governator5410 You did not specify a rule what to do with times like 11.59pm. So the end time for these entries will be the same as the start time. So this may cause problems. At the moment I determine end times from the start times of the *next* entry. If there is no next entry, start and end times are the same. How do you know that times go from 11pm to 1am? Is it always 2 hours?

Comment: no its not always two hours. it was just an example. maybe its better if the last row of each data is simply deleted before the foverlaps command to make things easier and avoid the same start and end times.

Comment: @governator5410 Deleting the last row per `Channel` from `table1_schedule` means we can't check for overlap of that entry with entries from `table2_watch`. That doesn't sound like a good strategy to me. That aside, these entries don't result in an error (based on your current sample data). It would really help if you could provide a representative minimal dataset that reproduces the error you're encountering. Otherwise this is a bit of a guessing game.

Comment: sorry im kind of new to stackoverflow and not sure where to provide the dataset. I already posted the minimal dataset as `dput()` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413841/r-joining-tables-using-time-intervals-error-using-foverlaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about doing this.  Note that I renamed some of your stuff.

```
> cat schedule 
Channel    Program      Date            StartTime
HBO        Mov A        1/1/2018        21:00
HBO        Mov B        1/1/2018        23:00
HBO        Mov C        1/1/2018        23:59
NatGeo     Doc A        1/1/2018        11:00
NatGeo     Doc B        1/1/2018        11:30
NatGeo     Doc C        1/1/2018        12:00
NatGeo     Doc D        1/1/2018        14:00
> cat watch
Person    Channel            Date        StartTime      EndTime
Name A    NatGeo             1/1/2018        11:00        12:00
Name B    NatGeo             1/1/2018        12:30        14:00         
Name B    HBO                1/1/2018        21:30        22:00
Name B    HBO                1/1/2018        22:30        23:30
```

Now, make sure we read these correctly using `readr`.  In other words, specify the correct formats for the dates and the times.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

schedule <- read_table("schedule",
                       col_types=cols_only(Channel=col_character(),
                                           Program=col_character(),
                                           Date=col_date("%d/%m/%Y"),
                                           StartTime=col_time("%H:%M")))

watch <- read_table("watch",
                    col_types=cols_only(Person=col_character(),
                                        Channel=col_character(),
                                        Date=col_date("%d/%m/%Y"),
                                        StartTime=col_time("%H:%M"),
                                        EndTime=col_time("%H:%M")))
```

Next, we convert all dates and times to datetimes and add an ending datetime to the schedule.

```
schedule <- schedule %>%
    mutate(StartDateTime=ymd_hms(paste(Date, StartTime))) %>%
    group_by(Channel) %>%
    mutate(EndDateTime=lead(StartDateTime, default=as_datetime(Inf))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(Channel, Program, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)

watch <- watch %>%
    mutate(StartDateTime=ymd_hms(paste(Date, StartTime))) %>%
    mutate(EndDateTime=ymd_hms(paste(Date, EndTime))) %>%
    select(Person, Channel, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
```

We can perform a join and check if the watch and schedule intervals overlap (you can modify this to accommodate to your 10 minute comment I believe, although I did not fully understand what you meant).

```
watch %>%
    inner_join(schedule,
               by=c("Channel" = "Channel"),
               suffix=c(".Watch", ".Schedule")) %>%
    filter(int_overlaps(interval(StartDateTime.Watch, EndDateTime.Watch),
                        interval(StartDateTime.Schedule, EndDateTime.Schedule))) %>%
    select(Person, Channel, Program, StartDateTime.Watch, EndDateTime.Watch) %>%
    rename_at(.vars=vars(ends_with(".Watch")),
              .funs=funs(sub("\\.Watch$", "", .)))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  Person Channel Program StartDateTime       EndDateTime        
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 Name A NatGeo  Doc A   2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 12:00:00
2 Name A NatGeo  Doc B   2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 12:00:00
3 Name A NatGeo  Doc C   2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 12:00:00
4 Name B NatGeo  Doc C   2018-01-01 12:30:00 2018-01-01 14:00:00
5 Name B NatGeo  Doc D   2018-01-01 12:30:00 2018-01-01 14:00:00
6 Name B HBO     Mov A   2018-01-01 21:30:00 2018-01-01 22:00:00
7 Name B HBO     Mov A   2018-01-01 22:30:00 2018-01-01 23:30:00
8 Name B HBO     Mov B   2018-01-01 22:30:00 2018-01-01 23:30:00
```

To get the desired output, you would have to group by everything except `Program` and "explode" the resulting groups into multiple columns.  However, I am not sure if that is a good idea so I did not do it.