# R- joining tables using time intervals error using foverlaps

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to merge two table data sets of two different tables (1) watching data, and (2) program schedule.

The goal is to to have the output such as all of the programs watched during the watching time interval is listed on the same row. 
The expected output

```
Person    Channel   program_Date  start_time  end_time  Prog1  Prog2   Prog3
Name A    NatGeo      1/1/2018      11:00       12:00     Doc A  Doc B  Doc C       
Name B    NatGeo      1/1/2018      12:30       14:00     Doc C  Doc D  -NA- 
Name B    HBO         1/1/2018      21:30       22:00     Mov A  -NA-   -NA- 
Name B    HBO         1/1/2018      22:30       23:30     Mov A  Mov B  -NA-
```

The sample data below is exactly the command and the error output in R studio and the two data sets in `dput()`. Im still learning R and I ma having trouble figuring out what the error actually means. And I have looked at [R- merging two data sets within time duration/intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280568/r-merging-two-data-sets-within-time-duration-intervals) and tried to exactly follow the procedure but it keeps on giving the error and still not sure why column in time1 does not correspond to column in time 2. Thanks

Sample data of dt1 & dt2. When the two lines are run there is error. I tried to fix but it still error:

```
> setkey(dt2_schedule, Channel, time1, time2)
 dt <- foverlaps(dt1_watching, dt2_schedule, by.x = c("Channel", "start", "end"), nomatch = 0L)
Error in foverlaps(dt1_watching, dt2_schedule, by.x = c("Channel", "start",  : 
  All entries in column time1 should be <= corresponding entries in column time2 in data.table 'y'



dt1_watching <- structure(list(Person = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name1", 
"name2"), Channel = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD"
), start = structure(c(1522564740, 1522566240, 1522566540, 1522654080, 
1522655760), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1522566000, 
1522567920, 1522567560, 1522656060, 1522658100), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009000788>, .Names = c("Person", 
"Channel", "start", "end"))

dt2_schedule <- structure(list(Channel = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD"), Program = c("NIGHT WATCH", "EXISTS", 
"MISSIONARY MAN", "NATURAL BORN KILLERS", "TANK 432", "EXTRATERRESTRIAL", 
"ENTRAPMENT", "GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID", "STRAW DOGS", "VICE", 
"INSURGENT", "LILA & EVE", "KILLING SALAZAR", "HACKER", "STRAW DOGS", 
"LOOSE CANNONS", "THE LAZARUS EFFECT", "SHARKTOPUS VS. PTERACUDA", 
"GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID", "EXISTS", "MAN VS.", "TANK 432", 
"LILA & EVE", "MISSIONARY MAN", "HACKER", "MAN ON FIRE", "A TIME TO KILL", 
"I HAD A BLOODY GOOD TIME AT HOUSE HARKER", "INSURGENT", "THE NEWTON BOYS"
), time1 = structure(c(1522555200, 1522561200, 1522562700, 1522568400, 
1522575300, 1522580700, 1522586700, 1522593600, 1522599600, 1522606200, 
1522611900, 1522619100, 1522624800, 1522630800, 1522637400, 1522644000, 
1522649700, 1522654800, 1522660200, 1522666200, 1522671000, 1522676100, 
1522681500, 1522687200, 1522692900, 1522699500, 1522708200, 1522717200, 
1522722300, 1522729500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    time2 = structure(c(1522561200, 1522562700, 1522568400, 1522575300, 
    1522580700, 1522586700, 1522593600, 1522599600, 1522606200, 
    1522611900, 1522619100, 1522624800, 1522630800, 1522637400, 
    1522557600, 1522649700, 1522654800, 1522660200, 1522666200, 
    1522671000, 1522676100, 1522681500, 1522687200, 1522692900, 
    1522699500, 1522708200, 1522717200, 1522722300, 1522643100, 
    1522729500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009000788>, .Names = c("Channel", 
"Program", "time1", "time2"), sorted = c("Channel", "time1", 
"time2"))
```

> un-modified data

```
> dput(dt1_watching)
structure(list(V1 = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name1", "name2"
), V2 = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD"), V3 = c("4/1/2018", 
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018"), V4 = c("2:39:00", 
"3:04:00", "3:09:00", "3:28:00", "3:56:00"), V5 = c("3:00:00", 
"3:32:00", "3:26:00", "4:01:00", "4:35:00")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009000788>)
> dput(dt2_schedule)
structure(list(V1 = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", 
"FOX Action Movies HD"), V2 = c("NIGHT WATCH", "EXISTS", "MISSIONARY MAN", 
"NATURAL BORN KILLERS", "TANK 432", "EXTRATERRESTRIAL", "ENTRAPMENT", 
"GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID", "STRAW DOGS", "VICE", "INSURGENT", 
"LILA & EVE", "KILLING SALAZAR", "HACKER", "STRAW DOGS", "LOOSE CANNONS", 
"THE LAZARUS EFFECT", "SHARKTOPUS VS. PTERACUDA", "GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID", 
"EXISTS", "MAN VS.", "TANK 432", "LILA & EVE", "MISSIONARY MAN", 
"HACKER", "MAN ON FIRE", "A TIME TO KILL", "I HAD A BLOODY GOOD TIME AT HOUSE HARKER", 
"INSURGENT", "THE NEWTON BOYS"), V3 = c("4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", 
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", 
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", 
"4/1/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", 
"4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", 
"4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/3/2018"), V4 = c("0:00:00", 
"1:40:00", "2:05:00", "3:40:00", "5:35:00", "7:05:00", "8:45:00", 
"10:40:00", "12:20:00", "14:10:00", "15:45:00", "17:45:00", "19:20:00", 
"21:00:00", "22:50:00", "0:40:00", "2:15:00", "3:40:00", "5:10:00", 
"6:50:00", "8:10:00", "9:35:00", "11:05:00", "12:40:00", "14:15:00", 
"16:05:00", "18:30:00", "21:00:00", "22:25:00", "0:25:00")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000009000788>)
```

Comment: Can you post your *raw* data for `dt1_watching` and `dt2_schedule`? I mean raw as in before converting time&dates to `POSIXct` and removing unnecessary columns as per my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51284056/6530970). The error comes about from two entries in `dt2_schedule` where `time1 > time2`. I'd like to see the source data to understand what happened.

Comment: ok its posted. thanks

Comment: Are dates in format "DD/MM/YYYY" or "MM/DD/YYYY"? I always assumed the former but now I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: i was also confuse but from what ive seen its `month/date/year` because the data is organized for the whole month

Comment: Right. That seems to have been (one of the) issues. Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: ok that makes sense. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok how about this?

```
library(data.table)

# Add column names
names(dt1_watching) <- c("Person", "Channel", "program_Date", "start_time", "end_time")
names(dt2_schedule) <- c("Channel", "Program", "program_Date", "start_time")

# Convert date & time to POSIXct
# Note that foverlap requires a start and end date, so we create an end date
# from the next start date per channel using shift for df1
dt1_watching[, `:=`(
    start = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, start_time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
    end = as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, end_time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))]
dt2_schedule[,
    time1 := as.POSIXct(paste(program_Date, start_time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")][,
    time2 := shift(time1, 1, type = "lead", fill = max(time1)), by = Channel]

# Remove unnecessary columns in preparation for final output
dt1_watching[, `:=`(program_Date = NULL, start_time = NULL, end_time = NULL)]
dt2_schedule[, `:=`(program_Date = NULL, start_time = NULL)]

# Join on channel and overlapping intervals
# Once joined, remove time1 and time2
setkey(dt2_schedule, Channel, time1, time2)
dt <- foverlaps(dt1_watching, dt2_schedule, by.x = c("Channel", "start", "end"), nomatch = 0L)
dt[, `:=`(time1 = NULL, time2 = NULL)]

# Spread long to wide
dt[, idx := paste0("Prog",1:.N), by = c("Channel", "Person", "start")]
dcast(dt, Channel + Person + start + end ~ idx, value.var = "Program")[order(Person, start)]
#                Channel Person               start                 end
#1: FOX Action Movies HD  name1 2018-04-01 02:39:00 2018-04-01 03:00:00
#2: FOX Action Movies HD  name1 2018-04-02 03:28:00 2018-04-02 04:01:00
#3: FOX Action Movies HD  name2 2018-04-01 03:04:00 2018-04-01 03:32:00
#4: FOX Action Movies HD  name2 2018-04-02 03:56:00 2018-04-02 04:35:00
#5: FOX Action Movies HD  name3 2018-04-01 03:09:00 2018-04-01 03:26:00
#                      Prog1                    Prog2
#1:           MISSIONARY MAN                       NA
#2:       THE LAZARUS EFFECT SHARKTOPUS VS. PTERACUDA
#3:           MISSIONARY MAN                       NA
#4: SHARKTOPUS VS. PTERACUDA                       NA
#5:           MISSIONARY MAN                       NA
```

The only difference to my previous answer is the calculation of end times for `df2_schedule`. **Note that you only have one `Channel`, so for multiple channels you will need to do this by `Channel` (hence the `by = Channel` above).**

---

### Sample data

```
dt1_watching <- structure(list(V1 = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name1", "name2"
), V2 = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD"), V3 = c("4/1/2018",
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018"), V4 = c("2:39:00",
"3:04:00", "3:09:00", "3:28:00", "3:56:00"), V5 = c("3:00:00",
"3:32:00", "3:26:00", "4:01:00", "4:35:00")), .Names = c("V1",
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"))


dt2_schedule <- structure(list(V1 = c("FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD", "FOX Action Movies HD",
"FOX Action Movies HD"), V2 = c("NIGHT WATCH", "EXISTS", "MISSIONARY MAN",
"NATURAL BORN KILLERS", "TANK 432", "EXTRATERRESTRIAL", "ENTRAPMENT",
"GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID", "STRAW DOGS", "VICE", "INSURGENT",
"LILA & EVE", "KILLING SALAZAR", "HACKER", "STRAW DOGS", "LOOSE CANNONS",
"THE LAZARUS EFFECT", "SHARKTOPUS VS. PTERACUDA", "GARM WARS: THE LAST DRUID",
"EXISTS", "MAN VS.", "TANK 432", "LILA & EVE", "MISSIONARY MAN",
"HACKER", "MAN ON FIRE", "A TIME TO KILL", "I HAD A BLOODY GOOD TIME AT HOUSE HARKER",
"INSURGENT", "THE NEWTON BOYS"), V3 = c("4/1/2018", "4/1/2018",
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018",
"4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018", "4/1/2018",
"4/1/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018",
"4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018",
"4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/2/2018", "4/3/2018"), V4 = c("0:00:00",
"1:40:00", "2:05:00", "3:40:00", "5:35:00", "7:05:00", "8:45:00",
"10:40:00", "12:20:00", "14:10:00", "15:45:00", "17:45:00", "19:20:00",
"21:00:00", "22:50:00", "0:40:00", "2:15:00", "3:40:00", "5:10:00",
"6:50:00", "8:10:00", "9:35:00", "11:05:00", "12:40:00", "14:15:00",
"16:05:00", "18:30:00", "21:00:00", "22:25:00", "0:25:00")), .Names = c("V1",
"V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"))
```